# Two network adapters, route deletion not persisting on reboot

Tags: 17.04, routing

I have two physical network adapters in my Ubuntu box.

My routing table is as follows:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp5s1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp5s1
```

the 192.168.2.x network accesses the internet, the 192.168.1.x network does not.

With the routing table above, I cannot access the internet so I delete the route as follows:

```
sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 0.0.0.0
```

This works fine and I can then access the Internet.

The problem comes when I reboot the PC as the route I just deleted comes back.

Is there anyway I can stop this?

I could probably add this to an rc.local script or a startup cron job but that seems a bit messy. Is there an 'accepted' way to delete the route without having to do it every startup?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809533/having-two-different-networks/809560#809560) may help.

Comment: Your best solution is probably to set the default gateway as 192.168.2.1.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 17.04 reached end-of-life on January 13, 2018. So it's off-topic here, but this issue doesn't appear to be version-specific. Still, you need to switch to a supported release like 18.04, if you haven't already.